# JOIN mysql table on PRIMARY KEY and JSON array

Tags: mysql, database

I have a Table, table1 with column

```
id name
1  A
2  B
3  C
4  D
```

And another table with column

```
id group
1  ["1","3"]
2  ["2","3"]
3  ["1","4"]
```

group is a JSON type field. I want to get records from first table according to the second table groups.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN (SELECT group FROM table2 WHERE id=1);
```

I tried the following query but not getting the result.

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(id, (SELECT group FROM table2 WHERE id=1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Wrong argument order. According to [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) JSON should be the first argument.

   ```
   SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE JSON_CONTAINS((SELECT group FROM table2 WHERE id=1), id)
   ```
2. Your JSON array contains strings, while you're looking for id that is `INT`. Try something like this:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE JSON_CONTAINS((SELECT `group` FROM table2 WHERE id=1), JSON_QUOTE(CAST(id as CHAR(50))))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id IN(SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(group) As id FROM table2 WHERE id= 1)
```